# Nested v-for in Vue app uses the previous state

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3, v-for

I am new to Vue.js and I am trying to code a decision tree but I am having an issue. When people click buttons on a step it loads another step based on a JSON file. The user should be able to skip back to a previous step and have it reset from that set and allow them to work through it from there.

The issue I am having is that the steps that are loaded after choosing a previous step will have the active class still applied. I am pretty sure this has to do with the `:key` on the `v-for` loop but I don't know how to reset it so that Vue is not saving that setting.

I have setup the code in a Codepen here https://codepen.io/akrug23/pen/jOVYQPd?editors=0011

You can reproduce what I am saying by clicking the following buttons

Manage it myself -> Low -> 0-5 years now click on Medium and you will see that the first button is already set with the class `active`

Note: Since a lot of the questions are the same I have added numbers to the front so you can see that other questions from the JSON file are loading. I am using Vue.js 3

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the key in the `BranchSteps` component to something unique to the question, like the `question` text in `item.question`:

```html
<div
  v-for="(item, index) in steps"
  :key="item.question"
  :data-step-id="index"
  class="card mb-2 js-step-card"
  :class="isLastCard(index)">
```

The reason for using a `key` in a `v-for` is so Vue won't reuse any existing DOM nodes when the list is re-rendered, such as when an item is added/destroyed.  But it only works if the key is unique to the list item.  Sometimes using `index` as a key is not unique enough, which is what's happening here.

The unique key above causes Vue to re-render the node with new info instead of reusing the ghost node of the removed item.